# Compiling a C++ subclass

Tags: c++

I'm getting confused with my C++ class structure below:

```
A.h:
  class A{
};

A.cpp
//implementation for A
  void A::someMethod();

B.cpp:
#include "A.h"

B : public A{

//stuff for B
};
int main{
   B b();
   b.someMethod();
}
```

g++ A.cpp A.h --> compiles fine

g++ B.cpp --> undefined reference to main

Comment: Post real code not pseudo code.

Comment: Would you care to spend 5 more minutes to make your question clear? With a compilable example perhaps. You have so many typos here I have no idea which one causes your problem

Comment: No semicolon at the end of your class?

Comment: did you miss the ; at the end of the class when copy pasted the code here or they were never there?

Comment: You need to post actual code.  Because this is a compile error, trying to replicate your code with pseudocode is not going to actually translate the problem you're having.

Comment: My apologies. I didn't post actual code since it's very long, and didn't seem relevant.

Comment: @Raghu: In that case you should create a minimal example that reproduces the problem, and post that minimal example as is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do:

```
g++ A.cpp -c
g++ B.cpp -c
```

To generate A.o and B.o (without `-c` g++ expects to link and produce a complete executable - and expects a `main` function, whereas -c specifies compile and assemble but do not link).

You can then link the two object files into an executable using:

```
g++ A.o B.o
```

Also: do not specify the header files on the command line. You need to specify them using `#include` directives in your cpp files and then the compiler will pull their contents in directly as the pre-processing stage of compiling each cpp. If you're interested in the details of the stages of compilation for C++, Microsoft have detailed those for their compiler [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxss3ska.aspx).

Comment: Not exactly "find" the headers, and not exactly compiler - rather preprocessor, and it will just copy-and-paste them. It's common that newcomers don't understand why something works/doesn't work just because they think there is some magic behind header files.

Comment: @Griwes: I have incorporated your suggestions for clarification. Thanks.

Comment: @Raghu. No problem. Seemed a bit harsh to close this off, but hopefully you've gotten your answer... :-)

Comment: @Alex - I did! I'll be more careful.